# How to get list instead of QuerySet class list in Django 2.2.6 version?

Tags: python, django

Currently I have migrated my py2 project in py3 django project & I am facing problem because of `QuerySet` word in new project.

**Py2 code & output**

```
Contact.objects.filter(is_default = False).values_list('name', flat= True)[:2]
[u'town', u'country']
```

**Py3 code & output**

```
Contact.objects.filter(is_default = False).values_list('name', flat= True)[:2]
<QuerySet ['town', 'country']>
```

I want to have same output as I am getting in py2 without `QuerySet` & does anyone have idea how should I do it?

Why does this extra `QuerySet` included in Django new version.

Thanks.

Comment: It will effectively behave the same as a list. What issue do you face with treating that result as a list?

Comment: It depends on what you do next with the queryset: a lot behaves similar to a normal list, e.g., you'd iterate through it as you would do through a list.

Comment: Both are `QuerySet`s. But in the Python-2.x version, it was simply represented as a list with a debatable `__repr__`.

Comment: To get a list from it, you can wrap `list()` around it: `list(Contact.objects.filter(...)....[:2])`

Comment: @deceze - I have used magicsuggest in my project so it will throw me `bundle.min.js?v=1.5:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error for this line of code  `def[att.name] = att.name === 'value' && att.value !== '' ? JSON.parse(att.value) : att.value;` .

Comment: There's a whole lot between this and that! Look at your browser's developer tools' network inspector to see what the actual server response looks like! It's probably telling you about some error that happened, which doesn't necessarily have anything to do with this QuerySet. And/or, check Django's error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like a list. But in case you want to have exactly "list" just wrap it.

```
list(Contact.objects.filter(is_default=False).values_list('name', flat=True))
```

Comment: When doing wrapping using list I am getting error `*** Error in argument: "(Contact.objects.filter(is_default = False).values_list('name', flat= True))"`

Comment: Provide please more details. Several lines above and upon the query and full error.